# How to display data in Fragment and Activity (both independent) from same Snapshot Listener (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-storage, android-livedata

Would like to have your help on my weird problem that currently I am facing. I tried for couple of days but no luck and finally decided to post here to take help.

I created a Snapshot Listener attached to a Collection in Firebase defined as follows :-

```
public class FirebaseTypingStatusLiveData extends LiveData<List<documentSnapshot>> {
// Logging constant
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseQueryLiveData";
// Document Reference
    private final DocumentReference documentReference;
 // Listener
    private final MyDocumentListener listener = new MyDocumentListener();
    // Handler
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;
    // Flag to remove listener
    private boolean listenerRemovePending = false;

    private MutableLiveData <List<documentSnapshot> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

 // Constructor
    public FirebaseTypingStatusLiveData(DocumentReference documentReference) {
    this.documentReference = documentReference;
    }

    public LiveData<List<documentSnapshot>> checknow(){

      // Add listener
        if (!Listeners.LIVESAMPLE.containsKey(documentReference)) {
            listenerRegistration = documentReference.addSnapshotListener(listener);
            Listeners.LIVESAMPLE.put(documentReference, listenerRegistration);

        } else {
        listenerRegistration = Listeners.LIVETYPINGSTATUSSAMPLE.get(documentReference);
        }
    return mutableLiveData;
    }

    // Listener definition
    private class MyDocumentListener implements EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable 
        FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent");
            // Check for error
            if (e != null) {

            // Log
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't listen to query snapshots: " + documentSnapshot
                    + ":::" + e.getMessage());
            return;
            }
            setValue(documentSnapshot);
            mutableLiveData.setValue(documentSnapshot);

               }

          }
        }
     }
```

The snapshot reads the data perfectly and advised as and when data is available.

The snapshot data is getting displayed 1. in Fragment (not part of Activity that i am talking about) 2. Activity through two view models that have the same code as follows :

```
    @NonNull
    public LiveData<List<documentSnapshot>> getDataSnapshotLiveData() {
        Firestore_dB db = new Firestore_dB();
        DocumentReference docref = db.get_document_firestore("Sample/"+docID);
        FirebaseTypingStatusLiveData firebaseTypingStatusLiveData = new 
        FirebaseTypingStatusLiveData(docref);
        return firebaseTypingStatusLiveData.checknow();
    }
```

The Fragment & Activity code is also same except changing owner which are as follows :-

```
LiveData<List<documentSnapshot>> liveData = viewmodel.getDataSnapshotLiveData();
     liveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<documentSnapshot>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(DocumentReference docreef) {
            String name = docreef.get("name");
                        stringname.setText(name); // The text is displaying either in Fragment or in Activity but not in both.
      });
```

My problem is i need data in both i.e. Fragment & Activity whereas I am getting data either in Fragment or in Activity depending upon the code which I commented.

Kindly advise where I am making mistake. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I am not sure that my answer wouldn't lead you away to the false way, but you can try.

My guess is that your problem could be somehow connected with ViewModel sharing.
There is a well-known task [How to share Viewmodel between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing).
But in your case, that can't help, because you have to share ViewModel between activities (now you have two separate ViewModels and that could be problem with Firestore EventListeners).

Technically you can share ViewModel between activities (I haven't try since usually I use Single activity pattern). For that as a **owner** parameter in [ViewModelProvider constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner)) you can set instance of your custom Application class (but you have implement interface [ViewModelStoreOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner) for it). After that both in your activity and in your fragment you can get the same ViewModel with the Application class-instance:

```
val sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(mainApplication, viewModelFactory).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Sorry for responding late. Thanx for your response. I did try your method and can be workable as well but since my Activity get opened up from different Fragments and Activity I need to change ViewModel in all such activity. Instead I made LiveData static that listens to changes in data and provide updated content were ever required.

Answer (score 0):

I made LiveData static that listens to changes in source data and provide updated content were ever required in different Activity.